# Multiple Facebook scripts?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

This may be kind of a dumb question, but the script for the facebook button on the like button page is different from the script on the javascript sdk page, but similar. Did facebook just forget to update the documentation or do I need both scripts?

The like button page gives:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script> (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

But on the javascript sdk page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

// Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is intentional.

Those who would use the javascript SDK are likely to want to do more than simply add a like button, therefore they include the fb.init script and show you where you add further initialisation code etc.

Those who are just adding a like button can just paste the other blob, which covers up the fbinit stuff to avoid confusion and complexity with this line:
`(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));`

I imagine if you try both, they'll both work :)